# Ubuntu won't start after nVidia driver installation GF8600GTS Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

After installing nvidia drivers, the system does not start. I tried to install drivers through Software & Updates and through the nVidia installer. The effect is the same. I only see a blinking underscore. The system does not react to any shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to be my Go-To solution on NVIDIA. Tell me if this works for you: http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, after doing everything according to this solution, the effect is the same.